# NUMBER is automatically getting converted to DECFLOAT

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I am new with DB2. I am trying to run an alter query on an existing table.

Suppose the EMP table is Already there in db which have below columns

`id int`
`name varchar(50)`

Now I am trying to Add a new column Salary for that I am running below query.

`ALTER TABLE EMP ADD SALARY NUMBER`

The above query run successfully. After that I described the EMP table it gave me below result:

`ID INTEGER`
`NAME VARCHAR`
`SALARY DECFLOAT`

As I am trying to add a column with NUMBER datatype, I dont know how NUMBER is getting converted to DECFLOAT.

It will be helpful if anybody can explain this.

**Db2 version details are as follow :**

`Service_Level: DB2 v11.1.2.2`

`Fixpack_num : 2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Db2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, with NUMBER data type enabled (it is not the default), this is the [documented](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.porting.doc/doc/r0052879.html) behaviour.

Specifically

> The effects of setting the number_compat database configuration
>   parameter to ON are as follows. When the NUMBER data type is
>   explicitly encountered in SQL statements, the data type is implicitly
>   mapped as follows:
>
> ```
> If you specify NUMBER without precision and scale attributes, it is mapped to DECFLOAT(16).
> If you specify NUMBER(p), it is mapped to DECIMAL(p).
> If you specify NUMBER(p,s), it is mapped to DECIMAL(p,s).
> ```